# Problems getting started with Chirp SDKs for Android

Tags: android, chirp

I have downloaded SDK for Android from 
    https://developers.chirp.io/downloads
After that I added *.aar library as was explain here: 
    https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#AddDependency
Hurrah. I can build the project.
Now I want to install the test App on the phone. But the application crashes like this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: io.chirp.sdkdemoapp, PID: 12979
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;
        at io.chirp.chirpsdk.ChirpSDK.<init>(Unknown Source:2)
        at io.chirp.chirpsdk.ChirpSDK.<init>(Unknown Source:5)
        at io.chirp.chirpsdk.ChirpSDK.<init>(Unknown Source:8)
        at io.chirp.sdkdemoapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:77)
```

As I understand it, a problem arose with dependencies when packaging * aar 
So I added in build.gradle (marked as Module) dependency for kotlin like:
implementation  'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.61'

After that my ERROR has changed.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: io.chirp.sdkdemoapp, PID: 13395
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/MediaType;
        at io.chirp.b.a.<init>(Unknown Source:24)
        at io.chirp.chirpsdk.a.<init>(Unknown Source:36)
        at io.chirp.chirpsdk.ChirpSDK.<init>(Unknown Source:20)
        at io.chirp.chirpsdk.ChirpSDK.<init>(Unknown Source:5)
        at io.chirp.chirpsdk.ChirpSDK.<init>(Unknown Source:8)
        at io.chirp.sdkdemoapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:77)
```

I have wrong paths to io.chirp internal libraries.

What should I do to resolve dependency related errors?

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the `okhttp` 3.12.x dependency required by the ChirpSDK.

However, you don't need to explicitly import the dependency if you are using the SDK from the maven repository as this will be already included:

```
implementation 'io.chirp:chirpsdk:3.10.0'
```

and add the repository in your parent maven file:

```
repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.chirp.io/release"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maven repository doesn't work in my case (proxy issues or something else but this is the topic of another discussion). Thanks Dinu for your answer! The problem with using offline ChirpSDK was solved by adding two dependencies:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dinu for your answer!

Maven repository doesn't work in my case (proxy issues or something else but this is the topic of another discussion).

The problem with using offline ChirpSDK was solved by adding two dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.6'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.50'
```